# Add notes per each row/column in Table element

Tags: enterprise-architect

I use `Table` element on the UI diagram.
I can add `notes` for the whole table.

How can I add description per a specific cell/row/column?

I use a User Interfacediagram. The Table is element from the wireframing toolbox, its stereotype is "WireframeTable".
 I would like to have the ability to add different description to each cell 
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you using any kind of DB Query, if so, which kind? Questions kinda vague.

Comment: What type of diagram are you using and which MDG Technology does it belong to? What type of element are you creating? What's its stereotype? What types of feature do you wish to add notes to (attribute, operation, tagged value...)?

Comment: @Xariez, This is related to Enterprise Architect tool

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I have no knowledge whatsoever in that so can't help you myself. @user3165438

Comment: @Uffe, Thanks. I use a `User Interface`diagram. The Table is element from the wireframing toolbox, its stereotype is "WireframeTable". I would like to have the ability to add different description to each cell.

Comment: Update your question with the additional info you gave in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In EA you can only add notes to elements and features. 
But since the WireFrameTable only consists of a single element, and the cells are only graphical boxes (controlled by the tagged value `Properties`), you cannot enter individual comments on those.

So you can either figure out a mechanism to document the cells in the notes of your table element, or you can model the individual cells as separate entities such as a text field and document them that way.